# No puedo crear un directorio en el perfil de otro usuario

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito crear un directorio en el directorio *Mis Documentos* (`C:\Users\nombreUsuario\Documents`) pero Visual Studio me muestra la siguiente excepción:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\AR\Documents\BackUp_optimizador' is denied.'

Éste es el código que he usado:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(directorioRespaldo))
{
    /*Si el directorio en especifico no existe*/
    string nuevoDirectorio = @"C:\Users\AR\Documents\BackUp_optimizador";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(nuevoDirectorio); //--> Se genera la excepcion.
    directorioRespaldo = nuevoDirectorio;
}
```

Estoy ejecutando el proyecto usando una cuenta de administrador.

También me dirigí a la carpeta *Mis Documentos* y desactivé el atributo de *Solo lectura*.

Comment: ¿Es una aplicación compilada en un `.exe`? Si es así necesitarás escalar privilegios con UAC.

Comment: Si, esta compilada en .exe.
Como le doy privilegios con UAC.

Comment: Aunque hayas iniciado sesión con un usuario administración los permisos con los que se ejecutan las aplicaciones son limitados. Para que la aplicación que vas a ejecutar se ejecute con privilegios elevados debes pulsar el botón derecho sobre la aplicación y luego en "Ejecutar como administrador". Si todo va bien, te dejará crear el directorio. Dime si te funciona así y si es así te digo cómo solicitar UAC automáticamente al iniciar la aplicación.

Comment: Si me funciono gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque hayas iniciado sesión con un usuario administrador los permisos con los que se ejecutan las aplicaciones son limitados.

Para que la aplicación que vas a ejecutar se ejecute con privilegios elevados debes utilizar una de las siguientes alternativas:

- Pulsar el botón derecho sobre la aplicación y en el menú contextual seleccionar la opción "Ejecutar como administrador".
- Modificar las propiedades del ejecutable pulsando el botón derecho sobre él y luego en "Propiedades". En la pestaña "Compatibilidad" puedes activar la opción "Ejecutar este programa como administrador". Tras aplicar los cambios verás que aparece un escudo sobre el icono de la aplicación.
- Modificar el archivo de manifiesto del programa para que éste solicite escalada de privilegios ([UAC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_de_cuentas_de_usuario)) al ejecutar la aplicación.

Para realizar esto último deberás seguir las siguientes instrucciones:

En Visual Studio debes ir al menú "Proyecto" y luego en "Agregar nuevo elemento...". Aparecerá una ventana en la que debes eligir "Archivo de manifiesto de aplicación (solo Windows)".

Una vez abierto el archivo de manifiesto debes cambiar en él la siguiente línea:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Por la siguiente:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede crear una carpeta en su computadora mediante programación, crear una subcarpeta, crear un archivo en la subcarpeta y escribir datos en el archivo.

por ejemplo:

```
public class CreateFileOrFolder
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Specify a name for your top-level folder.
        string folderName = @"c:\Top-Level Folder";

        // To create a string that specifies the path to a subfolder under your
        // top-level folder, add a name for the subfolder to folderName.
        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, "SubFolder");

        // You can write out the path name directly instead of using the Combine
        // method. Combine just makes the process easier.
        string pathString2 = @"c:\Top-Level Folder\SubFolder2";

        // You can extend the depth of your path if you want to.
        //pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, "SubSubFolder");

        // Create the subfolder. You can verify in File Explorer that you have this
        // structure in the C: drive.
        //    Local Disk (C:)
        //        Top-Level Folder
        //            SubFolder
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

        // Create a file name for the file you want to create.
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();

        // This example uses a random string for the name, but you also can specify
        // a particular name.
        //string fileName = "MyNewFile.txt";

        // Use Combine again to add the file name to the path.
        pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);

        // Verify the path that you have constructed.
        Console.WriteLine("Path to my file: {0}\n", pathString);

        // Check that the file doesn't already exist. If it doesn't exist, create
        // the file and write integers 0 - 99 to it.
        // DANGER: System.IO.File.Create will overwrite the file if it already exists.
        // This could happen even with random file names, although it is unlikely.
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(pathString))
            {
                for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    fs.WriteByte(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" already exists.", fileName);
            return;
        }

        // Read and display the data from your file.
        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathString);
            foreach (byte b in readBuffer)
            {
                Console.Write(b + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
    // Sample output:

    // Path to my file: c:\Top-Level Folder\SubFolder\ttxvauxe.vv0

    //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
    //30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
    // 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 8
    //3 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
}
```

Si la carpeta ya existe, CreateDirectory no hace nada y no se lanza ninguna excepción. Sin embargo, File.Create reemplaza un archivo existente por uno nuevo. El ejemplo utiliza una instrucción if- elsepara evitar que se reemplace un archivo existente.

Al realizar los siguientes cambios en el ejemplo, puede especificar diferentes resultados en función de si ya existe un archivo con un nombre determinado. Si dicho archivo no existe, el código crea uno. Si tal archivo existe, el código agrega datos a ese archivo.

Especifique un nombre de archivo no aleatorio.

```
// Comment out the following line.  
//string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();  

// Replace that line with the following assignment.  
string fileName = "MyNewFile.txt";
```

Reemplace la instrucción if- else con la instrucción using en el siguiente código.

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(pathString, FileMode.Append))
{  
    for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)  
    {  
        fs.WriteByte(i);  
    }  
}
```

Ejecute el ejemplo varias veces para verificar que se agreguen datos al archivo cada vez.

Para obtener más FileModevalores que puede probar, consulte FileMode .

Las siguientes condiciones pueden causar una excepción:

El nombre de la carpeta tiene un formato incorrecto. Por ejemplo, contiene caracteres ilegales o solo es un espacio en blanco ( clase ArgumentException ). Utilice la clase Path para crear nombres de ruta válidos.

La carpeta principal de la carpeta que se creará es de solo lectura ( clase IOException ).

El nombre de la carpeta es null( clase ArgumentNullException ).

El nombre de la carpeta es demasiado largo ( clase PathTooLongException ).

El nombre de la carpeta es sólo dos puntos, ":" ( clase PathTooLongException ).

Comment: Es buena idea compartir el artículo original en el que has basado tu respuesta cuando te has limitado a copiar/pegar el contenido de ella: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario :)